# Get file path from a remote server

Tags: python, django, server

Hi I'm having a hard time in getting the file path from a remote server. Is there any one from here that could be able to help me?

What I want to achieve is to play an audio file that has been save in a remote server.

This is what my code looks like right now. This is not yet working.

```
<audio controls>
<source 
src="user@host:/file/path/from/remote/server/{{record.filename}}" type="audio/ogg">
</audio>
```

What I want to know is how could I be able to get this path `user@hostname:/file/path/from/remote/server`

I'm using Django with Python.

Thanks a lot for anyone that could help!

Comment: Why not get the file first to your local and then use it like this src="location/in/local"? You can use requests.get("user@host:/file/path/from/remote/server/{{record.filename}}") to get the resource. Any specific reason for not using this?

Comment: I will be having thousands of file that will be uploaded. I don't want to pile up all those files in my disk. Thanks for your response I'll try your suggestion.

Comment: Hi! can you please elaborate on how to use requests.get("user@host:/file/path/from/remote/server/{{record.filename}}"). I'm quite new into this. Thanks!

Comment: Became too large a comment, added as an answer. Hope it helps.

Comment: Please accept the ans if it solved your issue. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

You must be rendering the template( the part of which you show in your question ) from a views.py function. In that view, download the file to your local:

```
import requests
# Before rendering the template 
r = requests.get("user@host:/file/path/from/remote/server/" + record.filename)
local_file = "/path/on/local/" + record.filename
with open(local_file, 'wb') as f:
    f.write(r.content)
# Now pass the location of the local file in template render 
...render(local_file = local_file)
```

In your template, change accordingly

```
<audio controls>
<source 
src="{{local_file}}" type="audio/ogg">
</audio>
```

Now, you don't need to download all the files at once, if you are concerned about memory on local or about cluttering. Also, for efficiency you can maintain a map of all files downloaded by introducing a bool 'downloaded' field in the record. Then you can check this field before downloading and download only if not already on your local.